# Formula to count the text in a rang of cells (with formulas)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, microsoft-excel

I’m trying to have an Excel formula that counts the number of cells filled with text from a range of cells. The problem I have when using `=counta` is that the cells I’m trying to count all have their own formulas so the `=counta` formula is counting the “blank” cells as ones with data and adding them in the total.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
=counta( iferror( filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)) ) )
```

Alternatively, modify the formula cells you are counting so that the formulas return truly blank values `iferror(1/0)` instead of zero-length text strings `""`. The `counta()` function will consider `iferror(1/0)` blank but will consider `""` not blank.